# Determining thrust equations for a custom UAV

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, aerospace-engineering, aerodynamics, thrust

I have been tasked to mathematically model and simulate a 2 propeller, 2 motor UAV. But I am struggling with determining the thrust equations, of the propeller, for my design.

**I know that:**

**Ft = Ct * rho * (w/(2*pi))^2 * D^4**

*Where **rho** is the density of air ;*

***D***, the diameter in meters of the propeller;

***Ct***, the thrust coefficient;

*And **w** is the angular velocity of the propeller.*

**However, I was not given Ct although it is necessary for this equation.**

I have been told I can use something called the  "experimental propeller force-thrust constant" or **Kf** (units: N/V) to calculate **Ct** however, after multiplying **Kf** by the voltage of the motor driving the propeller, I am at a total loss as to how to do so.

*I used dimensional analysis in an attempt to receive a clue to the equation:*

**Ct = Ft/(rho*(w/(2*pi))^2*D^4)**

*Therefore **Ct**'s units are*

**N/((kg/(m^3))*(rev^2/sec^2)*m^4)**

*Which is equivalent to:*

**(N * sec^2)/(kg * rev^2*m)**

*Using the definition N = Kgm/s^2 the units of Ct are rev^-2.*

*Using the last two unit expressions I have arrived at this equation:*

**Ct = Kf * V / ((w/(2*pi))^2 * D * m)**

*Where V is voltage and m is mass.*

The units work, but I know that doesn't mean its correct.

Can anyone kindly verify if this equation is actually correct? Otherwise can someone please explain how to achieve the equation for **Ct** using **Kf**?

Any constructive comments are much appreciated. Please forgive my visually unfriendly web math notation.

Comment: Plane or 'copter type? Hovering and slow advance for 'copters is fairly tricky.

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for your response. This is for a helicopter style UAV. At this point I am not too concerned about that. I merely need it off the ground. Any input would be highly appreciated.